# hosting page on github.io

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to create a website on Github "shouttolearn.github.io" but when I create a repository with the name **shouttolearn.github.io** and publish, it supposes to that my index file should live on this URL [shouttolearn.github.io](https://shouttolearn.github.io) but it is showing a 404 error and one page create with URL  https://shouttolearnorg.github.io/shouttolearn.github.io/ why this creating page I want to live this URL "shouttolearn.github.io"

PS: shouttolearnorg is my GitHub username

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Tutorial on [Github](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site) and check your repository settings. Have a look under "Pages".

For me it works fine under the URL USERNAME.github.io page (see [here](https://millerluki.github.io/) my Github Page).
Make sure your repository is named right and your Repository is Public